# Problems figuring out a relational division query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've run into a problem of some complexity for my small brains to grasp. I have 4 tables, a user table that contains a user id ,a table report that contains the user id and the item id ,a table item that contains the id and a coordinate(lon,lat) and a table location that contains a bunch of coordinates(lon, lat).

I want to know which users reported an item on ALL of the locations above a certain latitude in the year X.

I know that it will involve a relational division of some sorts but I can't write the query for it.

What I'm thinking is that I want to select the users that don't fit the following criteria: From all the locations above a certain latitude, take away those that were reported by a specific user. if that returns empty, that means that the user has reported an item on ALL the locations above that latitude. Now, can you give me some help with the query part?

EXAMPLE:

- USER_TABLE

  ```
  user_email
  tony@gmail.com
  john@gmail.com
  geo@gmail.com
  ```
- REPORT_TABLE

  ```
  user_email     | item_id
  tony@gmail.com | 1
  geo@gmail.com  | 2
  geo@gmail.com | 3
  ```
- ITEM TABLE

  ```
  item_id | lat
  1       | 10
  2       | 15
  3       | 20
  ```
- LOCATIONS

  ```
  lat
  5
  10
  15
  20
  ```

In this case, if I want ALL the users that have reported an item on a location with a lat value above 12, it should return 
 geo@gmail.com 
 because he has reported an item on lat = 15 and lat = 20 which are the lat values for all the locations that are above a latitude value of 12.
He geo had only reported 1 item, then the return should be empty

Comment: @GordonLinoff how do I format the information in this case?

Comment: The `NOT EXISTS` clause will help.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yeah I know. It's the inner query that I can't figure out. How do I combine the lat values from ITEM with the ones from LOCATION and know which users reported an item in that location?